# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) при использовании itsdangerous.URLSafeTimedSerializer

Tags: python, flask

Пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
>>> from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
>>> s = Serializer(bytes('secret', 'utf-8'), 30)
>>> token = s.dumps({'user_id': 1}).decode('utf-8')
```

Возникает следующая ошибка: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `URLSafeTimedSerializer`, который наследуется от `Serializer`, в качестве второго аргумента ожидает соль, представленную либо как строку, либо как байты.

Также, использование `.decode('utf-8')` в последней строке необязательно, т.к. `token` уже возвращает строку, а не `bytes`. Вот рабочая версия кода:

```py
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
s = Serializer(bytes('secret', 'utf-8'), 'your_salt_here')
token = s.dumps({'user_id': 1})
print(token)
# eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.ZD901g.YFEMm-c4xG5RcMEQhkndKBuQ2gc
```